# Is this good programming style. Is it efficient to use class methods like this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I am somewhat new to Objective-C and iOS development (about 1.5 years working with it and really just the last 8 months or so getting heavily involved).  I have written a custom class that handles all my web-service requests.  I use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for these requests (and love it), but I want to make sure that what I am doing is efficient and not going to cause issues later.

From what I can see with Instruments and how the app performs, this seems like a good way to do it, but I am really far from being an expert and would like some feedback and/or advice.

Here is my NetworkClient class:

NetworkClient.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

extern NSString * const APIKey;

@interface NetworkClient : NSObject

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
             alertUserOnFailure:(BOOL)alertUserOnFailure
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block;

+(void)handleNetworkErrorWithError:(NSError *)error;

+(void)handleNoAccessWithReason:(NSString *)reason;

@end
```

NetworkClient.m:

```
#import "NetworkClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

NSString * const APIKey = @"MyAPIKeyThatIsDefinedInDatabasePerApplication";

@implementation NetworkClient

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {

    [self processURLRequestWithURL:url andParams:params syncRequest:NO alertUserOnFailure:NO block:^(id obj) {
        block(obj);
    }];
}

+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {
    [self processURLRequestWithURL:url andParams:params syncRequest:syncRequest alertUserOnFailure:NO block:^(id obj) {
        block(obj);
    }];
}


+(void)processURLRequestWithURL:(NSString *)url 
                      andParams:(NSDictionary *)params 
                    syncRequest:(BOOL)syncRequest
             alertUserOnFailure:(BOOL)alertUserOnFailure
                          block:(void (^)(id obj))block {

    // Default url goes here, pass in a nil to use it
    if (url == nil) {
        url = @"https://MyURLToWebService";
    }

    // Add in our API Key
    NSMutableDictionary *newParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:params];
    [newParams setValue:APIKey forKey:@"APIKey"];

    NSURL *requestURL;
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:requestURL];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:url parameters:newParams];

    __block NSString *responseString = @"";

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *_operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest];
    __weak AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = _operation;

    [operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        responseString = [operation responseString];

        id retObj = [responseString JSONValue];

        // Check for invalid response (No Access)
        if ([retObj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            if ([[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"No Access"]) {
                block(nil);
                [self handleNoAccessWithReason:[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Reason"]];
            }
        } else if ([retObj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            if ([(NSArray *)retObj count] > 0) {
                NSDictionary *dict = [(NSArray *)retObj objectAtIndex:0];
                if ([[dict valueForKey:@"Message"] isEqualToString:@"No Access"]) {
                    block(nil);
                    [self handleNoAccessWithReason:[(NSDictionary *)retObj valueForKey:@"Reason"]];
                }
            }
        }
        block(retObj);
    } 
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                          NSLog(@"Failed with error = %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Error]:%@",error]);
                                          block(nil);
                                          if (alertUserOnFailure) {
                                              // Let the user know something went wrong
                                              [self handleNetworkErrorWithError:operation.error];
                                          }

                                      }];

    [operation start];

    if (syncRequest) {
        // Process the request syncronously
        [operation waitUntilFinished];
    } 


}


+(void)handleNetworkErrorWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Error]:%@",error];

    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" 
                            message:errorString 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

}

+(void)handleNoAccessWithReason:(NSString *)reason {
    // Standard UIAlert Syntax
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                            initWithTitle:@"No Access" 
                            message:reason 
                            delegate:nil 
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                            otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [myAlert show];

}

@end
```

And here is how I call it:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"GetApplications", @"Command",
                            userInfo.networkID, @"NetworkID",
                            nil];

    [NetworkClient processURLRequestWithURL:nil andParams:params block:^(id obj) {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];

        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            myTableViewData = (NSArray *)obj;        
            [self.myTableView reloadData];  
        }
    }];
```

So my web-service can send back both a Dictionary structured JSON response and an Array formatted JSON response.  The NetworkClient method will take both and send back what it gets (I leave it up to the calling code to ensure it gets back what is expected).  I use the APIKey as additional security to ensure only my application can access web-service resources (the first thing I check before sending back data is that the APIKey matches that I have for that application in the DB).

Is this an efficient way to do this kind of thing?  Any ways to make it better?

Comment: What specifically do you perceive as inefficient?

Comment: I haven't seen any issues, but things like casting the obj as NSDictionary or NSArray and making a new Dictionary for adding in the APIKey have me wondering if that is going to be less efficient than some other way.

Comment: You don't need a cast to assign a value of type `id` to a more strongly typed variable (or vice versa).

Comment: Casting in Objective-C is free for most types (casting between primitives can incur a few cycles of expense doing conversion, but that's negligible.) It's never going to be a performance bottleneck for you.

Comment: In general, talking about "efficiency" and Objective-C in the same sentence is meaningless.  (And that applies to the previous sentence.)  Objective-C is never efficient, it's at best not terribly slow.  It's saving grace is that UI stuff is slower.

Comment: The dynamic nature of objc prevents a lot of optimizations that benefit C/C++, but the features causing that are [not badly implemented](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/). So to say it is inefficient (as in waste of resources), or that the productivity gained is not worth it is a statement hard to back with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you use `processURLRequestWithURL:nil` since this is made to deal with a specific service. It is also confusing, it only tells me that there is some magic elsewhere, which is the same as if it is not there at all. I would use a singleton:

```
extern NSString * const kBaseURL;

@interface NetworkClient : AFHTTPClient
+ (NetworkClient *) sharedClient;
@end

NSString* const kNodeApiURL = BASE_URL;

@implementation NetworkClient

+ (NetworkClient*) sharedClient
{
    static NetworkClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[NetworkClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseURL]];
    });
    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL*)url 
{
    if (self = [super initWithBaseURL:url]) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) init {
    error(@"Use initWithBaseURL: instead.");
    [super doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}

@end
```

and then on the PCH

```
#define BASE_URL  @"https://MyURLToWebService"
```

You are also mixing the GUI with the server API when you add a parameter to show a popup. I don't think the server API should block the thread ever. Write purely asynchronous code and let the caller block the GUI from his own end.

Same with the handleNoAccessWithReason. The API doesn't handle anything, it sucks an input and produces an output. Every piece of code you write should do one (1) thing. It's going to be a lot easier to test, understand, and reuse.

I don't know why you qualified the operation with __weak.

Those parameters you pass, it's going to be a lot easier to understand if you use domain objects like User and Command or whatever. Well, "Command" stinks. Is there really a method with a meaningful name behind your usage code? Because when I debug code where I have to print the parameters to tell what's going on I nerd enrage. If you are writing a server API (and by default you should if you want clean code), you should expose meaningful names.

I would write the code differently, example, I want a cow from the server for a given user:

```
typedef void (^AFJSONSuccess)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON);
typedef void (^AFJSONFailure)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON);

+(void) cowForUser:(User*)user callback:(void(^)(Cow *cow, NSError *error))callback {

    AFJSONSuccess success = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // turn JSON into a cow
        callback(cow,nil);
    };

    AFJSONFailure failure = ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        // create a custom NSError
        callback(nil,error);
    };

    NetworkClient *client = [NetworkClient sharedClient];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:kCowPath parameters:jsonDic];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:sucess failure:failure];
    [client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Now in usage start the hud, and in the callback block call stop hud and check if the cow is nil. I don't think the hud should block the screen (as you do waiting until the op is done), what if the user decides to move to another screen or cancel the query?

I'm voting to close this question because it belongs in code review.

Comment: Command is a meaningful name.  That is what is switched on my web-service to determine what server side code to run to bring back a json response from the SQL server.  The URL is passed as nil if I want to use the default URL for the app.  That leaves me the freedom to use a different URL for the web-service if I need to.  All I pass to the web-service is the form post params (APIKey, Command, etc) and then the logic is done on the web-server.  The Singleton method sounds nice and compact, I will have to look at that more (I actually considered that in the beginning).

Comment: The Cow example doesn't fit my needs at all though.  I get back lots of different formatted responses from the web-service depending on what I need.  Could be a JSON array for a TableView source.  Could be an JSON dictionary for a single object or whatever.  I didn't want 20 different methods in that class to return 20 different objects.  I feel as though using one method that handles all the requests is much easier to troubleshoot and tons less code to write.  It all comes back to one place.

Comment: If you operate on dictionaries with a trivial amount of data fine, if not, it's worth the trouble for the rest of the application to have a layer worrying about conversion to domain objects because Xcode autocompletion is easier than debugging, looking up on a reference, and accessing dictionary keys directly all over your code.